# Avoiding distkey and not creating a new tables before joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, select, amazon-redshift, inner-join

I've a dataset that looks like this:

| uuid | lang | name | text | abc | ijk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1231312 | en | general | this is a foo bar | 0.23 | 8 |
| 1231312 | en | general | this is a foo bar | 0.93 | 58 |
| 9890803 | en | general | another sent | 0.38 | 29 |

And a working query that looks like this:

```
CREATE temp TABLE new_xyz sortkey(
    uuid, lang, name, text
) distkey(uuid) as (
    SELECT
        uuid, lang, name, text, min(abc) as abcs, sum(ijk) as ijks
    FROM
        original_xyz
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
)
```

And there's another table that looks like this:

| uuid | trg_lang | rst |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1231312 | de | 0.95 |
| 1231312 | de | 0.34 |

And I've a 2nd query that looks like this:

```
CREATE temp TABLE new_qqq sortkey(
    uuid, trg_lang
) distkey(uuid) as (
    SELECT 
        uuid, trg_lang, min(rst) as rsts
)
```

And a final join query that looks like:

```
SELECT * from new_xyz nxyz
INNER JOIN new_qqq nqqq
ON nxyz.uuid = nqqq.uuid
```

To produce something like:

| uuid | lang | name | text | abc | ijk | trg_lang | rst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1231312 | en | general | this is a foo bar | 0.23 | 66 | de | 0.34 |

Is it possible to combine the 3 queries into 1?

To do so, I guess my question indirectly would be:

**Can the first two queries that uses `distkey(uuid)` be done without creating a temporary data?** If so, then we can do something like this

```
SELECT uuid, lang, name, text, abcs, ijks, trg_lang, rsts
FROM 
    (SELECT ... FROM xyz without the distkey) nxyz
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ... FROM qqq without the distkey) nqqq
ON (nxyz.uuid = nqqq.uuid)
```

Comment: You're answering your own question at the bottom of your post, what's the doubt you're having about it?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM xyz without the distkey` won't work without the distkey, won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a single query use the subqueries. Below is the subquery for the mentioned tables in the above: -

```
SELECT nxyz.uuid, nxyz.lang, nxyz.name, nxyz.text, nxyz.abcs, nxyz.ijks, nqqq.trg_lang, nqqq.rsts
FROM 
(
    SELECT uuid, lang, name, text, MIN(abc) AS abcs, SUM(ijk) AS ijks
    FROM original_xyz
    GROUP BY uuid, lang, name, text
) AS nxyz
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT uuid, trg_lang, MIN(rst) AS rsts
    FROM another_table
    GROUP BY uuid, trg_lang
) AS nqqq
ON nxyz.uuid = nqqq.uuid
```

The nxyz and nqqq subqueries perform same logic as first two queries. The result from nxyz and nqqq are stored in the subquery uuid.

Comment: This way won't the uuid not be unique in the sub-queries? Or would that be handled by groupby?

Comment: The sub-queries GROUP BY clause makes sure that each sub-query's UUIDs are distinct from the others. The UUID column is used to group the rows, making ensuring that each group represents a different UUID. The UUIDs will be distinct among the sub-queries as a result, and the GROUP BY clause will deal with any potential duplication.